# Selenium ClickInterceptedException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on a button with Selenium on python. The thing is that after I find the element using explicit waits, I get that another elements would recieve the click. I thought that maybe this button had a parent element with the same dimensions and this one was about to get clicked, but it isn't the case. I'm using chromedriver. I'll share the fragment of html code and what I'm doing:

```
<section id="main">
    <div id="form-signin">
        <img id="dynamic-logo" src="images/logo.svg" class="height-39px">
        <h3 class="clear-margin-bottom margin-top-22px">Sign in</h3>
        <div class="form-input margin-top-30px">
            <label>
                <input id="username" ng-model="data.user" ng-change="checkResetError()" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; login()" ng-class="{'has-error': errorMessage !== undefined }" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                <span class="placeholder">Enter your username</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input margin-top-30px">
            <label>
                <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="data.pass" ng-change="checkResetError()" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; login()" ng-class="{'has-error': errorMessage !== undefined }" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                <span class="placeholder">Password
                    <div class="frd-icon frd-icon-lock pull-right"></div>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <p class="font-xs font-bold fg-red pull-left margin-top-18px ng-binding"></p>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-frd btn-xl bg-blue btn-block" style="background-color: #00a8e1" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
    <span class="powered-text" ng-show="isFoundedLogo === true">Powered by <a href="https://www.test.com/" class="fg-white" target="_blank">Test</a></span>
```

And my code for the click part in python is like this:

```
login_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))).find_element_by_tag_name("button")
login_button.click()
```

I don't get why this happens. I also tried to find it by xpath, but the same error appeared.

Thanks

Comment: It is similar to StaleElementException. Are you getting this error all the time whenever you are running the script..?

Comment: Only on clicks. When I look for another elements and call send_keys works fine. I'm currently resolving it with js calls, but I don't like the idea of solving selenium problems with js, specially being something that should be too difficult